# How to do push navigation with Notification Observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two classes. A and B for example.

I have created an observer in A like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(somethingHappens:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
}
    
-(void)somethingHappens:(NSNotification*)notification
 {
    NavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
        
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loyaltyVC"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[vc];

 }
```

I want to call this observe from page B. I'm using like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:self];
```

Do you have any suggestion how we can do this ?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: i already use navigation push in the same page so there is no error with storyboard identifier etc. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise this are not push notifications. The following are just normal in-app-notifications.

Your `-(void)viewDidLoad` should contain a call to its super method at some point.

```
//in A
@implementation AThingy {
    id<NSObject> observeKeeper;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    observeKeeper = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"notificationName" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loyaltyVC"];
        nav.viewControllers = @[vc];
    }];
}
// not mandatory but to explain it complete
-(void)dealloc {
    // could be placed in some other method also.. like -viewDidDisappear:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observeKeeper];
}
@end
```

```
//in B
@implementation BThingy
-(void)postNotify {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:nil];
}
@end
```

But keep in mind that NotificationCenter is working *relative* to its observing Objects and so it matters if you watch and post in general on (`nil`) or on some specific object. Why is that? Because you could decide to instantiate two objects from the same class that observe notifications and still specifically observe each notification meant for them or both.

Comment: and think about if notifications are the right thing for u because what happens when two notifications arrive? Also possible a delegate/protocol design pattern is worth thinking about.

Answer (score -1):

1. Have you tried to print a log in method `somethingHappens:`?
2. Is your method `-(void)didLoad` ever been called?

Comment: Please don't use the answer section to request further information about the question. If you use the site a little longer you will soon be able to add comments, and that is where such questions belong.